# am developing an application with TabbarController using storyboard, is it good to use separate storyboards for each tabs?

Tags: iphone

How to use Multiple StoryBoards for switching tabs ?
Will there be any problems If I use multiple storyboards ? 
How can i navigate to a viewcontroller of storyboard1 to other viewcontroller of Storyboard2  ??

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a StoryBoard use it for your complete application. It is usualy (in what I did before) not a good idea to manage multiple storyboard.

If you want to add tabs to a tabBarController, simply add them from the toolbox by draging them in the screen of your StoryBoard. After this, link them to your tabBarControler by CONTROL-Draging them to your tabBarController (the blue line linker)

One more thing. Since xCode is a litle bit buged with the tabBarControllers, it freeze your tab making them unable to click and manage. Simply refresh your StoryBoard by clicking a code window and back to your storyBoard to make it working well.

Hope this helped you, feel free to ask if something is missing :)